# conditional validation for multiple registrations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have 2 fields that are being passed in request body. I have a conditional validation for if value1="OK" then value2 must be "PASSED" or raise a validationerror. It's working fine for single instance but in my json body I can pass multiple registration requests at once, like the Json request body shown below.

```
[
  {
    "Value1": "OK",
    "Value2": "NOTPASSED"
  },
  {
    "Value1": "OK",
    "Value2": "PASSED"
  }
]
```

How can I process second record, though validation for first record failed?

EDIT: Looking at the comments I thought to simplify the question even more:

these are the fields from request body:

```
@NotEmpty
private String value1;
@NotEmpty
private String value2;
```

I can pass multiple registrations in my json body as shown above.
let's say I passed a body like this:

```
[
  {
    "Value1": "",
    "Value2": "NOTPASSED"
  },
  {
    "Value1": "OK",
    "Value2": "PASSED"
  }
]
```

Since we have NotEmpty validation for value1, it will throw a validation error but second record with value1 as "OK" and value2 as "PASSED" doesn't have any validation errors. So I need a functionality to be able to process the second record while throwing error for the first record.

Comment: Can you share your logic for handling single registration?

Comment: So in the example above, Does it pass or fail?

Comment: Maybe **JSON Schema** could achieve this, but I am not sure.

Comment: take that list of object and loop then after make a if else condition and validate ..

Answer (score 0):

Request body is an array having multiple instances of

```
{
  "Value1": "OK",
  "Value2": "NOTPASSED"
}
```

You can loop through the array and validate each instance something like

```
        List<VallidationError> validationErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(RequestElement element: requestBody) {// RequestElement is the class for each instance in the request body
            if(element.getValue1().equals("OK") && !element.geValue2().equals("PASSED")) {
                validationErrorList.add(new ValidationError());// Add validation error to a list of validation errors
            } else {
                processElement(element);// Process the record here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> take that list of object and loop then after make a if else condition
>   and validate ..

```
list.forEach(object->{
   if(object.getValue1()=="OK")
    if(object.getValue2()=="PASSED")
    //do ur logic because if pointer come here means it's valid
    else
    //do ur logic if not valid like raise a validation-error
    //my suggestion is store invalid instances here and through in single 
    //shot

});
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the logic. I'm very new to all this

Answer (score 0):

As you said it can be **Empty String** sometimes then instead of using **@NotEmpty** you should use **@NotNull**.

I guess it should solve your problem as on an empty string for value1 it will not throw validation.

Comment: My question is even if it throws a validation error for first record I must be able to process the second one